# Reading data in csv

Tags: python

I have a csv file with only 1 column ticker. It looks like:

```
TIKCER
aapl
tsla
wmt
```

I am able to read it into python

However, when I print this out using for loop, it only print TICKER.

Can you please help to fix it?

Thank you,

HHC

```
import pandas as pd
list_ticker = pd.read_csv (r'C:\INV2021 data\sp500 constituent.csv')

##the list is read
print(list_ticker)

for line in list_ticker:
    ticker=line
    print(ticker)
```

Comment: list_ticker is a data frame you are only printing the column names

Answer (score 1):

if you need to print row by row you can use the method itertuples:

```
for line in list_ticker.itertuples():
    print(line)
```

Comment: This does print line by line but it get other information.
Pandas(Index=0, TICKER='aapl')
Pandas(Index=1, TICKER='tsla')
Pandas(Index=2, TICKER='wmt')
Pandas(Index=3, TICKER='GM')

Thus, the checking like below will not work

if ticker=='wmt':

        print(ticker)

Comment: what do you need to do with each line inside the loop?

Comment: I want to do comparison for further analysis, so at minimum I should be able to perform == operation

Comment: The good thing about dataframes is that you can do most of the analysis without iterating row by row. For example you can do list_ticker[list_ticker.ticker == 'wmt'] and this will select all the wmts without iterating.